# How can I find all primitive pythagorean multiples given one even number including that number?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations, maple, linear-diophantine-equations

I am trying to make an algorithm to find all pythagorean triples given a even number such as 4. Then the triple would be (3,4,5). Is there a way to do this?
I am using maple to do this but can also work with python.

My code so far is 
PythagoreanTriplets := proc (x) local y, z, a, b, primitive; x; 2*ab; y = a^2-b^2; z = a^2-b^2; primitive := sqrt(x^2+y^2); for a in divisors(x) do for b in divisors(x) and not a do if gcd(a, b) = 1 then primitive := print(x, y, z) end if end do end do; return primitive end proc

Comment: with a pair $p,q$ with at least one even you can get Pythagorean triples as $a=p^2-q^2, b=2pq, c=p^2+q^2$

Comment: yes but how can I generate the p and q values?

Comment: look, with $p=2$ and $q=1$ one generates your example, so... this could be the only one

Comment: I know I can do it by trial. I have edited my question now.

Comment: Given b, write a program that will list all factors of b/2.

Comment: Is it all right if I can come up with some code in python?

Answer (score 1):

Example.

Given an even number, say $40$, then $pq = 20$ and, if you are looking for only primitive Pythagorean triples, then $p \not \equiv q \pmod 2$. That leaves the following possibilities.

\begin{array}{c}
    p & q & p^2-q^2 & p^2+q^2 & \text{triple}\\
   20 & 1 &     399 &     401 & (40, 399, 401)\\
   10 & 2 \\
    5 & 4 &       9 &      41 & (9, 40, 41)
\end{array}